# How can I save the weight and biases of trained Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, autoencoder

I built neural network using tensorflow.

After training it and get the minimum cost, I need to save the weights and biases as matrices in order to be use in e.g.,  Matlab.  How I can do that?

When I perform the following code after finishing the training to save the weights:

```
from scipy.io import savemat
savemat("end_Weight1.mat", weights )
```

I can save it, but I get empty matrix, it means the matrix includes only the four variables but without any values. I don't get any values in the matrices.

I think the weights need to be updated before saving them or something like that ?

Comment: [scipy.io.savemat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html)?

Comment: @Corralien I got it, but I get empty matrix !

Comment: when do you save it ? Do you save it after training?

Comment: @furas, yes after the training

Comment: @Alrl which doc you mean ?

Comment: @furas I added the training step and the use of the save command.

Comment: you use it inside `with tf.Session() as sess:` - did you try to save after session? We can't run it so I can also suggest to use `print()` to check values in variables in different moment - ie. inside and outside session.

Comment: @furas Ok, I will run it again and save after the Session. I will let you know the output.   But, I am wondering, should the weights be updated ? I am not sure but I see that we use them inside the functions of encode and decode but we don't declare them as outputs of those functions. should they be updated ?

Comment: if you have class assigned to variable - ie. `w = tf.Variable()` and you assign it to other variable (or send to function) `t = w` and you change value inside `t` then you see this change in `w`. Python doesn't duplicate class when you assing `t = w` - so both variables points to the same object in memory.

Comment: @furas Even after the Session, the saved matrix is empty. I don't get any values. when I used 'print(print(weights)' after the Session, I get the following output: '{'encoder_h1': <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(8, 256) dtype=float32_ref>, 'encoder_h2': <tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=(256, 6) dtype=float32_ref>, 'decoder_h1': <tf.Variable 'Variable_2:0' shape=(6, 256) dtype=float32_ref>, 'decoder_h2': <tf.Variable 'Variable_3:0' shape=(256, 8) dtype=float32_ref>}'

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
all_variables=tf.global_variables()
```

on each batches to get your variables from created graph and then saved them.

> Note: this method return all variablen, for this reason you can filter the list.Ex get filter it by biases or weights as you want.

Comment: You mean I used it after declaring the weights, and then perform savemat("all_variable.mat", all_variables ) ? that will save all the variables ?

Comment: you can use it before savemat or anywhere in Session block

Comment: more information is available on tensorflow vesion 1.x for this method

Comment: yes, but when I used savemat("all_variable.mat", all_variables ) ,   it gives me an error as follows:  for name, var in mdict.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'